# Apache + FastCGI + Python under Windows 7

Tags: python, apache, windows-7, fastcgi

Помогите пожалуйста настроить связку Apache + FastCGI для запуска веб-приложений на Python в операционной системе Windows 7.

Используемое программное обеспечение:

- веб-сервер Apache 2.4 (C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe);
- модуль "mod_fcgid.so" (версия 2.3.9) для поднятия FastCGI в Apache (C:\Apache24\modules\mod_fcgid.so);
- Python 2.7.11 (C:\Apache24\bin\python\Scripts\python.exe)
- операционная система Windows 7 Максимальная x86.

Прописал в "httpd.conf" модуль "mod_fcgid.so" таким образом:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module "modules/mod_fcgid.so"

FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:/Apache24/bin/python/Scripts;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;C:/Apache24/bin;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/Windows/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/Windows/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"

FcgidInitialEnv SERVER_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
FcgidInitialEnv SERVER_NAME "localhost"
FcgidInitialEnv SERVER_PORT "80"
FcgidInitialEnv SERVER_PROTOCOL "HTTP"
FcgidInitialEnv REQUEST_METHOD "GET"

<IfModule fcgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/fcgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Allow from all
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Также добавил строку:

```
ScriptAlias /fcgi/ "c:/Apache24/fcgi-bin/"
```

в раздел  файла "httpd.conf".

После этого в списке подключенных модулей Apache появился "mod_fcgid.so":

```
httpd.exe -M
. . . . .
negotiation_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
fcgid_module (shared)
```

Установил все необходимые модули Python и написал простейшее flask-приложение "myapp.py":

```
#!C:/Apache24/bin/python/Scripts/python.exe
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
   return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

При запуске из консоли приложение корректно работает и отдает в браузер по URL (localhost:5000) строку "Hello World!".
И, наконец, создал скрипт "run.fcgi", который должен запускать приложение "myapp.py" через FastCGI:

```
#!C:/Apache24/bin/python/Scripts/python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from myapp import app

environ = dict(os.environ.items())
environ['SERVER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'
environ['SERVER_PORT'] = '80'
environ['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost'
environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = 'HTTP'
environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   WSGIServer(app, debug = True, environ=environ).run()
```

В итоге при запуске Apache и переходе в браузере по адресу
http://localhost/fcgi/run.fcgi
получаю ошибку:
"500 Internal Server Error"

а в логе ошибок Apache появляются следующие строки:

```
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:22.062069 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4020:tid 196] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:22.062069 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4020:tid 196] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:22.062069 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4020:tid 196] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.EXE -d C:/Apache24'
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:22.082069 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4020:tid 196] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2832
Apache server interrupted...
016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2832:tid 220] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:25.766076 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2832:tid 732] (OS 109) анал был закрыт.  : [client ::1:49407] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Mon Mar 28 15:00:25.768077 2016] [core:error] [pid 2832:tid 732] [client ::1:49407] End of script output before headers: run.fcgi
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно, почему не запускаются Python-скрипты через FastCGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать каталог myapp в нем файлы `__init__.py` и views.py каталог /templates/index.html
Я описал по этой ссылке
[Проблема с apache или с flask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511213/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-apache-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-flask?s=1|1.5568)
У меня заработало, но не совсем как хотелось (суть проблемы изложена). Запускаю просто через CGI, встречал в сети (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/fastcgi/) описание и запуска через FastCGI, но добавление переменных окружения там не было `environ = dict(os.environ.items())`