# Проблема с apache или с flask

Tags: python, apache, flask

Начну по порядку с описания 
ОC Linux Ubuntu 14….
Сервер apache2
Python 2.7
Структура каталогов:

```
Misite.local /
        / cgi-bin/
                /yourapplication
                               /templates
                                        /index.html
                              /views.py
                             /__init__.py
                /test.cgi 
       /.htaccess
```

*.htaccess* содержит `DirectoryIndex  /cgi-bin/testcg.cgi` и Options `-Indexes`

Файл  Apache  *misite.local.conf*

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/misite.local /cgi-bin/testcg.cgi
<Directory /var/www/misite.local/cgi-bin>
     AllowOverride All
     Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/misite.local >
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Файл  *test.cgi*

```
#!/var/www/home/menv/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from yourapplication import app
CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Файл  ***init**.py*

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import yourapplication.views
```

Файл `views.py`

```
from yourapplication import app
from flask import render_template
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/cgi-bin')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Testttt'}  # fake user
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user)
```

Файл */templates/index.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Welcome to microblog</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi, {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div><p>{{ post.author.nickname }} says: <b>{{ post.body }}</b></p></div>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Код перевод на  хабре (https://habrahabr.ru/post/193242/) или  (http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

При обращение _http://misite.local/cgi-bin  работает. Не смотря на декоратор @app.route('/') при обращение  _http://misite.local,   возвращает

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Если поставить в файле  Apache *misite.local.conf*

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/misite.local/cgi-bin/
```

Возвращает

> The requested URL was бла бла бла

Почему `from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler`, на хостинге работает только cgi, нужно что б все обрабатывалось, типа  _http://misite.local/  и т.д.

Ума не приложу что делать, в инфе уже утонул за два дня скитаний по гуглу.
При том не ясно, куда копать, в сторону apacha или flask(а). (Хорошо что вообще заработало).

Как правильно это все дело оформить? И ещё, на хостинге у меня доступа к конфигам апача не будет, только к .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился. В чем подводные камни, решил написать таким же как я, новичкам, думаю профи не понадобится. Файл Apache misite.local.conf в 

`<Directory /var/www/misite.local/cgi-bin> AllowOverride None`,

это всего лишь розрешения на обработку .htaccess. 
`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/misite.local/cgi-bin/` исправил на 
`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/misite.local/cgi-bin/` (слеш добавил)

Касательно .htaccess, как не странно взято с отсюда http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/cgi/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Don't interfere with static files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/the/application.cgi/$1 [L]
```

только заработало после удаления комментария # и все что за ним.
естественно  `/path/to/the/application.cgi/` заменил на `/cgi-bin/test.cgi` и добавил `RewriteBase /`

(По модулю mod_rewrite отличные публикаций _https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/mod_rewrite_guide.txt.html , _https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/mod_rewrite/ и _https://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/)

Файл (скрипт) views.py

```
from yourapplication import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user = {'nickname':'Test1'}   
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user)                          
@app.route('/home')
def index1():
    user = {'nickname':'Test2'}  
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user)

@app.route('/tst')
def index2():
    user = {'nickname':'Test3'} 
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user)
```

Обратите внимание, название функций разное (на всякий случай) и если у вас к примеру в корне сайта (/) будет директория /home то apache полезет в неё и функция в скрипте не обработается, бесспорно с помощью mod_rewrite или как то по другому с этим можно бороться, но я не ставил за цель с этим разбираться. В целом тест на хостинге пройден, можно углубляться в изучение Flask